# How to configure my own AutoTimer in Spring 6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, micrometer

I am working on the migration of the metrics of our app from the old APIs relying on WebMvcMetricsFilter to the new one, based on Micrometer 1.11, because we are migrating from Spring Boot 2.7.14 to 3.1.4.

**Our previous metrics setup was as follows:**

Before we were using a filter implementing `WebMvcMetricsFilter`:

```
public class AppWebMvcTimersFilter extends WebMvcMetricsFilter {

private final Predicate<String> predicate;


public AppWebMvcTimersFilter(
  final MeterRegistry registry,
  final WebMvcTagsProvider tagsProvider,
  final String metricName,
  final AutoTimer autoTimer,
  final Predicate<String> predicate) {
  super(registry, tagsProvider, metricName, autoTimer);
  this.predicate = predicate;
}

@Override
protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
  return predicate.test(request.getRequestURI());
 }
}
```

Then we had our implementation of `AutoTimer`defining our own buckets, like so:

```
public class AppMetricAutoTimer implements AutoTimer {
  @Override
  public void apply(Timer.Builder builder) {
    builder
     .minimumExpectedValue(Duration.ofMillis(BUCKET_0))
     .maximumExpectedValue(Duration.ofMillis(BUCKET_10))
     .sla(
        Duration.ofMillis(BUCKET_0),
        Duration.ofMillis(BUCKET_1),
        Duration.ofMillis(BUCKET_2),
        Duration.ofMillis(BUCKET_3),
        Duration.ofMillis(BUCKET_4),
        Duration.ofMillis(BUCKET_5),
        Duration.ofMillis(BUCKET_6),
        Duration.ofMillis(BUCKET_7),
        Duration.ofMillis(BUCKET_8),
        Duration.ofMillis(BUCKET_9),
        Duration.ofMillis(BUCKET_10));
  }
}
```

And the two things bond in a Metrics configuration class to declare the beans:

```
  @Configuration
  public class AppMetricsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    MeterRegistry appSimpleMeterRegistry() {
      return new AppSimpleMeterRegistry(aggregatedTotalLatenciesLoader());
    }

    @Bean
    AutoTimer appMetricAutoTimer() {
      return new AppMetricAutoTimer();
    }

    @Bean
      WebMvcTagsProvider appWebMvcTagsProvider() {
        return new AppWebMvcTagsProvider();
    }
    
    @Bean
    WebMvcMetricsFilter appWebMvcTimerFilter(
      final MeterRegistry registry,
      final WebMvcTagsProvider metricWebMvcTagsProvider,
      final AutoTimer appAutoTimer) {
      return new AppWebMvcTimersFilter(
        registry,
        metricWebMvcTagsProvider,
        METRIC_FULL_NAME,
        appAutoTimer,
        uri -> !uri.startsWith(URI_API_PREFIX));
      }
    }
```

**With the change of Observation APIS in Spring 6**:

Now I've got rid of the `WebMvcMetricsFilter`. As before, we are configuring an interceptor to use a `MeterRegistry` to handle the different counters. But due to the removal of our implementation of `WebMvcMetricsFilter`, all of our tests verifying the latencies are now failing.

I haven't found in the documentation any way to provide a bean of `AutoTimer` to have the latencies sorted as per our configured buckets.

The question is: how is it supposed now to provide an `AutoTimer` in a similar way it was done before in the implementations of `WebMvcMetricsFilter`?

Answer (score 0):

AutoTimer is not used anymore, if you want to modify your meters, you can either:

1. Set things from properties, e.g.:

```
management.metrics.distribution.slo.http.server.requests=...
management.metrics.distribution.minimum-expected-value.http.server.requests=...
management.metrics.distribution.maximum-expected-value.http.server.requests=...
```

Please check the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.actuator.management.metrics.distribution.slo).

2. You can create a MeterFilter and do the same from code:

```java
@Bean
MeterFilter sloMeterFilter() {
    ...
}
```

Please check the [boot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.metrics.customizing) and the [micrometer](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_configuring_distribution_statistics) docs.

Comment: thanks jonatan... I promise I check the docs before asking, but it is not pretty obvious how the old setup based on WebMvcMetricsFilter is now translated into the new obserbavility API. The fact that AutoTimer is still there, not deprecated, made me think there was a way to configure it as before.

Comment: Boot 2.x instrumented web-mvc using Micrometer's Timer (the instrumentation was in Boot). Starting from Boot 3.x, this instrumentation was moved to Spring Framework 6 (into web-mvc itself) using the Observation API. I think `AutoTimer` should be deprecated but let me ask the Boot team (you can also create an issue asking for deprecation).

Comment: I've already created the issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/31509. Thanks for the tips.